# Prove: $n \in Z^{\geq 2}$, $f_nf_{n+1} - f_{n-1}f_{n+2} = (-1)^{n+1}$

Tags: induction

$n \in Z^{\geq 2}$, $f_nf_{n+1} - f_{n-1}f_{n+2} = (-1)^{n+1}$.

How do you do the inductive step of this proof, every time I do it I cannot find a way to use the definition of a Fibonacci sequence to simplify the right side of the equation enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep using Fibonacci recursion for "large" numbers like $n+1,$ $n+2$ and $n+3:$
$$
\begin{aligned}
f_{n+1}f_{n+2}-f_nf_{n+3}&=f_{n+1}(f_{n+1}+f_n)-f_n(f_{n+2}+f_{n+1})\\ \\&=f_{n+1}(f_{n+1}+f_n)-f_n(2f_{n+1}+f_n)\\ \\&=(f_n+f_{n-1})(f_{n+1}+f_n)-f_n(2f_{n+1}+f_n)\\ \\&=f_nf_{n+1}+f_n^2+f_{n-1}f_{n+1}+f_{n-1}f_n-2f_nf_{n+1}-f_n^2\\ \\&=f_nf_{n+1}+f_{n-1}f_{n+1}+f_{n-1}f_n-2f_nf_{n+1}\\ \\&=f_{n-1}(f_n+f_{n+1})-f_nf_{n+1}\\ \\&=f_{n-1}f_{n+2}-f_nf_{n+1}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach to how you might discover this result.

Notice that
$$
f_nf_{n+1} - f_{n-1}f_{n+2} =
\det \begin{pmatrix}f_{n}&f_{n+2}\\f_{n-1}&f_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}
$$

Using the definition of the Fibonacci sequence, we have
$$
\begin{pmatrix}f_{n}&f_{n+2}\\f_{n-1}&f_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}f_{n-1}&f_{n+1}\\f_{n-2}&f_{n}\end{pmatrix}
$$
and so, by induction,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}f_{n}&f_{n+2}\\f_{n-1}&f_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^{n-1}
\begin{pmatrix}f_{1}&f_{3}\\f_{0}&f_{2}\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^{n-1}
\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now take determinants, noting that $(-1)^{n-1}=(-1)^{n+1}$.

Comment: A very nice approach, also allows one to find  $\det \begin{pmatrix}f_{n}&f_{n+a+1}\\f_{n-1}&f_{n+a}\end{pmatrix}$ as an alternating sequence

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Matrix_form